# data.table weird behaviour when used in a function

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a `data.frame` as follows.

```
data <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("S01", "S02", "S03"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Alan", "Bruce", "Jay"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Barry", "Dick", "Hal"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Guy", "Jean-Paul", "Wally"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bart", "Damien", "John"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

It is not a `data.table`

```
is.data.table(data)
[1] FALSE
```

I have a function `foo` for example which utilizes `data.table` for doing some manipulations in the `data.frame` as follows.

```
foo <- function(df) {
  if(!is.data.frame(df)) stop('"df" is not a data.frame')
  setDT(df)
  setkey(df, V1)
  df[, "NEW" := paste0(V3, V4), with = FALSE]
  setDF(df)
  return(df)
}
```

However when I run the function with the `data.frame` `data` (not a `data.table`), the output `out` is a `data.frame` (because of `setDF(df)`).

```
out <- foo(data)
is.data.table(out)
[1] FALSE
```

But now the original `data.frame` `data` is a `data.table`.

```
is.data.table(data)
[1] TRUE
```

I understand this is because `data.table` works by reference. However how to deal with this when being used in a function. I dont' wan't to inadvertently change any data.frame in environment. Should I always force copy with `copy` or `<-` instead of `setDT` whenever `data.table` is used in a function, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to

> is there another way?

Instead of `setDT()` inside the function, you could use `as.data.table()`

```
foo <- function(df) {
    if(!is.data.frame(df)) stop('"df" is not a data.frame')
    df <- as.data.table(df)
    setkey(df, V1)
    df[, NEW := paste0(V3, V4)]
    setDF(df)
    return(df)
}

foo(data)
#    V1    V2    V3        V4     V5           NEW
# 1 S01  Alan   Hal       Guy   John        HalGuy
# 2 S02   Jay Barry     Wally   Bart    BarryWally
# 3 S03 Bruce  Dick Jean-Paul Damien DickJean-Paul

is.data.table(data)
# [1] FALSE
```

For some examples of functions that turn the input data *frame* into a data *table* but do not change the original data frame at all, I'd definitely recommend looking at source code for the functions in package `splitstackshape`.